# Как сделать мультиязычное приложение на C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нигде не нашёл толкового решения поэтому прошу помощи кто знает.

Как я понял это делается через ресурсы, но как точно так и не понял, помогите решить.

На просторах интернета нашёл данный код:

```
public static void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
    foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
    {
       LocalizeForm(frm);
    }
}

public static void LocalizeForm(Form frm)
{
    var manager = new ComponentResourceManager(frm.GetType());
    manager.ApplyResources(frm, "$this");
    ApplyResources(manager, frm.Controls);
}

public static void ApplyResources(ComponentResourceManager manager, Control.ControlCollection ctls)
{
   foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
   {
      manager.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
      ApplyResources(manager, ctl.Controls);
   }
}
```

Он изменяет язык как я понял через ресурсы, но как правильно его использовать?

Что мне нужно сначала сделать, создать отдельный файл в ресурсах?

P.S: В English не силён поэтому на других бордах тяжко ориентироваться.

Comment: [Глобализация и локализация приложений .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/), [Общие сведения о глобализации и локализации WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview)

Comment: @tym32167, У меня winforms

Comment: значит одна из двух ссылок, что я вам дал, не подойдет, а вот вторую почитайте.

Comment: [Windows Forms localization demo (CSWinFormLocalization)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinFormLocalization-59675a87)

Comment: @tym32167, Было бы не плохо если бы расписали в ответе)) А как можно сделать изменения языка допустим по нажатию на label чтобы изменялся нужный язык?

Comment: Я не WinForms уже много лет не пишу, но умею гуглить, потому вам скинул сылки, а не писал ответ :)